# How to get the corresponding value from two objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have first data object which has a list of cafe, and second data object which has a list of cafe types.

I need find, get and display the corresponding **type** value from first data object and **ID** value from second data object.

For example: in list of cafe, I have *Pinta* with `"type" : "3"`, it means that **3** is **Bar** from second object.

First object:

```
{
  "list": {
      "item": [
          {
              "ID": "31",
              "name": "Staut",
              "type": "1",
          },
          {
              "ID": "34",
              "name": "Pinta",
              "type": "3",
          }
      ]
   }
}
```

And second object:

```
{
  "list": {
      "item": [
          {
              "ID": "1",
              "name": "Restaurant",
          },
          {
              "ID": "2",
              "name": "Cafe",
          },
          {
              "ID": "3",
              "name": "Bar",
          }
      ]
   }
}
```

I can do it with **Lodash**. It is right, but I can't display it and it uses high memory.

```
getValues: function() {
  _.forEach(CafeJSON.list.item, function(cafeValue) {
    _.forEach(TypeJSON.list.item, function(typeValue){
      if (cafeValue.type == typeValue.ID) {
        console.log("Cafe name is: ", cafeValue.name, "and type is: ", typeValue.name)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: Also, you're working with literals, not JSON. JSON is a string representing a subset of JavaScript.

Comment: @EmileBergeron It is JSON I get it from my backend.

Comment: Once received, it is parsed and it's no longer JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify the types object down to a object having key value pairs in the form of `'3': 'Bar'`, then loop the items once, overriding the `type` property's value.

```js
let list = {
  "list": {
    "item": [{
        "ID": "31",
        "name": "Staut",
        "type": "1",
      },
      {
        "ID": "34",
        "name": "Pinta",
        "type": "3",
      }
    ]
  }
}

let types = {
  "list": {
    "item": [{
        "ID": "1",
        "name": "Restaurant",
      },
      {
        "ID": "2",
        "name": "Cafe",
      },
      {
        "ID": "3",
        "name": "Bar",
      }
    ]
  }
}

let typesSimplified = types.list.item.reduce((a, b) => {
  a[b.ID] = b.name;
  return a;
}, {});

list.list.item.forEach(e => {
  e.type = typesSimplified[e.type];
});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Please just have a look on the variable names in above code @Zhanserik